# Let $f$ be a bounded twice differentiable real valued function on $\mathbb R$ such that $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. Then $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded twice differentiable real valued function on $\mathbb  R$ such
that $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. Then how to show that $f$ is a constant function.
please give me some hint.

Comment: Hint: If $f'(c)>0$ for some $c$, what can you say about $f'(x)$ for $x>c$?

Comment: For this sort of question, it would be instructive to try to write a "hand-wavy" proof and then expand it into a formal one. So "It has to be constant because if it has positive slope anywhere its slope has to get larger and the function won't be bounded any more" would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you so much.It is now clear to me @Hugh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that $f''\geq0$, $f$ is convex. This implies that $f$ lies weakly above its tangent line at any point. Formally, for any $x_0\in\mathbb R$,
$$f(x)\geq f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$
Now, if $f'(x_0)>0$, then the right-hand side goes to infinity as $x\to\infty$, which contradicts $f$ being bounded. Similarly, if $f'(x_0)<0$, then the right-hand side diverges to $\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$, which implies that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty$, another contradiction. It follows that $f'(x_0)=0$. Since this is true for any $x_0\in\mathbb R$, $f'=0$, so that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Because $f'' \geq 0$, $f'$ is nondecreasing. Suppose that there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_0) \neq 0$. If $f'(x_0)>0$, because $f'(x)\geq f'(x_0)$ for all $x \geq x_0$, we have $$f(x)=f(x_0)+ \int_{x_0}^x f'(t)dt \geq f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0) \underset{x \to + \infty}{\longrightarrow}+ \infty.$$

If $f'(x_0)<0$, because $f'(x) \leq f'(x_0)$ for all $x \leq x_0$, we have $$f(x)=f(x_0)-\int_{x}^{x_0} f'(t)dt \geq f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0) \underset{x \to - \infty}{\longrightarrow} + \infty.$$

Therefore, if $f$ is bounded, necessarily $f'=0$, that is $f$ is constant.